# mysqldbexport not excluding tables - "Variable 'foreign_key_checks' is a SESSION variable"

Tags: mysql, database-backups

I'm trying to move from a ISAM mysql database to an InnoDB mysql database (10's of millions of records/rows). So, I'm trying to use mysqldbexport to export just the data from the tables so that we don't need to adjust the sql files once exported. I'm trying to use the following command and it doesn't actually exclude the required tables.

mysqldbexport --server=username:password@localhost db_name --export=data --bulk-insert --exclude=db_name.table_name --output-file=full_db_name_export.sql

Originally started on version:

> MySQL Utilities mysqldbexport version 1.5.6

This failed to exclude the table. It also fails to complete the export anyway, presumably due to resource (memory) limitations.

I then updated to:

> MySQL Utilities mysqldbexport version 1.6.5

I now get the error:

> Source on localhost: ... connected. ERROR: Query failed. 1238 (HY000): Variable 'foreign_key_checks' is a SESSION variable

I have tried using the command SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; on the mysql command line and it just complains saying that it's a SESSION variable.

Can anyone help with either fixing the issue with the first version not excluding or, help me with getting around the issue with the second version? Or better yet, give me a "lmgtfy" link that works :)

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error using mysqldbcopy,you could solve it by 2 ways:
1.upgrade destination MySQL to a higher version that supporting syntax--`SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0`
2.comemnt out this line `destination.disable_foreign_key_checks(True)` in source file `.../site-packages/mysql/utilities/command/dbexport.py`